# Connection pooling in gems that open connections to network services

Tags: ruby, connection-pooling

I'm working on a series of gems for dealing with Sphinx 2 & realtime indexes, standalone, with Datamapper and with ActiveRecord.  It (obviously) opens a connection to Sphinx, in order to do this.

https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus

```
Oedipus.connection("sphinxql.host.tld:9306")
```

Right now I'm not doing anything fancy about managing connections... if the user of the gem makes a connection, a new connection is opened and that is that.  It is the user's responsibility to manage that connection.  However, other gems seem to bring a concept of pooling and I never really get the point in a single-threaded environment.

Could somebody please enlighten me as to *why* pooling might be necessary, what the consequences of my K.I.S.S. approach are, and how I might add pooling?  Does pooling only really make sense in a multi-threaded application, where effectively one connection exists per thread, or are there other valid use cases?  If it's just for multi-threaded apps, isn't this something the user could probably manage better than the gem making assumptions?

I'm guessing for a threaded implementation, a simple "unlimited connections" approach would be:

```
def connection
  Thread.current[:oedipus_connection] ||= connect(args)
end
```

So when the thread goes away, so does the connection (cleanup happens when the resource is freed).

It's been playing on my mind and I'm wondering if not having built-in connection pooling/management is going to come back to haunt me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally only multithreaded apps need multiple connections.  It's theoretically possible for a single-threaded app to make use of multiple connections but there probably isn't a good reason for that.

The main benefit of a connection pool is to keep database connections for re-use, to minimise the overhead of setting up new database connections.  This can matter in a typical request-per-connection scenario like rails where each request may result in just one or a few database queries.  Then the connection setup becomes a significant portion of the request time.

But it's a bit of a PITA to set up a proper connection pooling system.  You have connection timeouts and cleanups to worry about.  Check the [ActiveRecord connection pooling code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb) for an example.

You can defer having to worry about connection pooling by creating an using the right interface.  It would go something like

```
class MyConnection
    def self.get1(args)
        # establish a connection and return it
    end

    def close
        # close the connection
    end
end
```

Or maybe

```
def use_connection
  connection = nil
  begin
    connection = open_a_connection
    yield connection
  ensure
    connection and connection.close
  end
end
```

And then you can make the interface more sophisticated later on, without having to touch the rest of the app.

Comment: I hadn't thought about connection timeouts actually; this may be a reason to add it.  If a user keeps a connection open for too long, the server will likely terminate the connection.  The connection probably needs to be expired and a new one returned if it's past, say 60 seconds old.  Thanks.  In two minds really.  Maybe I'll just make the pooling opt-in, rather than implicit.

Comment: I got something implemented, that I think is ok. https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus/blob/master/lib/oedipus/connection/pool.rb Slammed it with 8 threads simultaneously for a long time, but the pool wouldn't grow in size. Scaled up to 80 threads simultaneously (for my own sanity) and bingo, pooling magic happening. Thanks for the help :)